# tailwindcss background image with arbitrary values cannot get load?

Tags: tailwind-css

**Description -** The images cannot get loaded as a background.

**Screenshots -**

[image: See here]

[image: See]

[image: See]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to use `tailwind.config.js`.

Just define the image path in `tailwind.config.js` file like this.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'galaxy': "url('http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg')",
        'tree': "url('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/riceracer_assets/img/tree_3.png')",
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And then use `bg-keyvalue`. like `bg-galaxy` here to utilize them in the pages like this.

And use like

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="mx-auto mt-16 grid w-8/12 grid-cols-3 text-white grid-rows-3 gap-4 bg-slate-200">
  <div class="row-span-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-tree">block1</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-galaxy">block2</div>
  <div class="row-span-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-blue-400">block4</div>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-blue-400">block5</div>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-blue-400">block3</div>
  <div class="flex h-40 items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-blue-400">block6</div>
</div>
```

YOu can see my tailwind play link as an example [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jB1FXMPrCH)

Comment: the path is dynamic and it's impossible to put it on tailwind.config.js\